# Sort Django QuerySet by distinct reverse FK

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

This shouldn't be too hard using the ORM; it's super easy using raw SQL.

I have some models:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    specialty = models.ManyToManyField(Specialty, blank=True)
    allergy = models.ManyToManyField(Allergy, blank=True)
    #.... TONS MORE M2Ms HERE ....#

class Character(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
```

I believe this is the correct modeling, since one actor plays many characters, but in most cases, the reverse is not so, e.g.:

```
m = Actor(last_name='Palin')
d = Character(actor=m, name='Dennis')
r = Character(actor=m, name='Right Head')
```

If I want to display a list of all actors, and get all their m2m relationships, that's easy:

```
actors = Actor.objects.all().prefetch_related(specialty, allergy, ...)
```

There are a series of pretty complex filters that can be applied to the above queryset, based on user input, e.g., `actors allergic to peanuts but not allergic to filth`.

Now if I want to get the same queryset, sorted by **distinct character names**, the only way I know of is to query Characters, select related actors, and prefetch related m2ms.

Unfortunately, that will require me to re-write all the filters. Because `allergy__name='peanuts'` would have to become `actor__allergy__name='peanuts'`.

What's the answer? How do I offer "sort by actor" and "sort by character" in the **DRY**est way possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-write the Actor filters, how about using an Actor QS to constrain the Character filter? Example:

```
actors = Actor.objects.filter(allergy__name='peanuts')
chars = Character.objects.filter(actor__in=actors)
```

Then you can order `chars` however you wish.

**Edit**: I see the problem you're having, I think. You want Characters to prefetch with the other records related to Actor. This is a good use case for select_related() ex:

```
actors = Actor.objects.filter(allergy__name='peanuts').select_related('character_set').prefetch_related()
```

This should yield all matching Actors with the related Character records included in your result set, allowing you to sort on Character name without hitting the database each time. The last `prefetch_related()` brings over all the M2M records, assuming you want those too.

**Another Edit**: From here, there are many ways to re-order or re-organize the resulting data. One possible way to represent this as Character records (with preloaded Actors) might be:

```
from itertools import chain
by_chars = chain(*[a.character_set.all() for a in actors])
```

Or, if it's more readable / maintainable:

```
by_chars = []
for a in actors:
    for c in a.character_set.all():
        by_chars.append(c)
```

Since you've preloaded everything, additional sorting and grouping of the result set shouldn't require any additional trips to the database.

Comment: Well, that would work, but then there's no `prefetch_related` happening. There would be lot's of database activity on the template end. Consider 3000+ Actors and 5-6000 Characters.

Comment: Filtering is not dependent on prefetching. Note that I'm not returning the *results* of the Actor QS, I'm using it to filter the Characters. That's just one trip to the database. Once you're all done ordering/filtering `chars`  as a QS, you can apply `.prefetch_related()` if that's what your use case requires.

Comment: How then do I display all the actors, sorted by character name. Where, in the example above, 'Palin' would have two entries. This would result in many queries.

Comment: Not quite: If I choose all actors, by actor name, I get one, `<Actor: Palin>`. If I choose all actors, by character name, I want 2, but it will be the same queryset. I need to return `<Actor: Palin, Char_name: 'Dennis'>, <Actor: Palin, Char_name: 'Right Head'>`.

Comment: @RobL That's just a bit of extra grouping of the retrieved data. A couple possible ways to do that have been added.

Comment: That's cool, it will give me a list of characters. What I need is a QuerySet of actors, one per character, sorted by character name.

Comment: @RobL I've already shown the most performant way to do this. It matters not at all whether the QS is on the Characters model or the Actors model so long as you end up with the data you need ordered/grouped in the way you need.